# RavenDB and Inserting data

Tags: nosql, ravendb

I recently started using RavenDb. I am converting a relational dbase to use RavenDb. I have two simple tables in the Relational dbase:

tbStates
tbCities

I have all US cities linked to a state. How can I go about converting this to no-sql. Will I have to write a little application to read from the relational dbase and create the objects? Or are there some tools out there I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a utility called smuger http://ravendb.net/documentation/smuggler but I imagine you will have to convert your data to Json. It may be just as easy to write a console app that reads the tables to objects then loads to Raven.

Comment: Thanks, I sort of figured I would have to do that. Was hoping there would be an easier way. Trying to come up with ways to initialize the dev and production servers. In MS-SQL I would write a script to populate these read-only tables.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add I migrated a SQL Server database to RavenDB using the console application route.

I used EF to quickly pull out the data and converted it to my RavenDB domain then added it to RavenDB.

It Worked well as you will most likely want to tweak the domain anyway to work best with RavenDB (For example I had an Images SQL table that I turned into a List on the document etc).

See Ayende's RacoonBlog project on github (https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog) as he does something similar to move subtext data to RavenDB. RacoonBlog is the engine powering his blog and makes for good learning material about how to use RavenDB.